# Отсортировать по убыванию объекты по дате создания

Tags: c#, сортировка

```
var products = _galleryProductRepository.GetFiltered(filter)
               .ToList();

        var temp=null;

        for (int i = 0; i < products.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < products.Count; j++)
            {
                if (products[i].CreatedDate < products[j].CreatedDate)
                {
                    temp = products[j];
                    products[j] = products[i];
                    products[i] = temp;
                }

            }
        }
```

Выдает ошибку - Cannot assign null to an implicity-typed variable.
В связи с чем вопрос - что присвоить temp?

Comment: Напишите вместо var тип переменной. Компилятор не может вывести из null тот тип, который должен скрываться под var.

Comment: @DreamChild - добавьте в ответ, помогло

Comment: почему не просто `var products = _galleryProductRepository.GetFiltered(filter).OrderByDescending(x=>x.CreatedDate).ToList();` ?

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо, воспользуюсь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var products = _galleryProductRepository.GetFiltered(filter).OrderByDescending(x=>x.CreatedDate).ToList();
```